# Algolia Firebase Syncing - AlgoliaSearchNetworkError :(

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, algolia

I followed the documentation [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/integrations/firebase-algolia/) to a node.js client syncing Firebase with Algolia. Everything should be setup correctly, however when I try to run node, I get this error:

```
AlgoliaSearchNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND t29y6y0wwc t29y6y0wwc:443
    at ClientRequest.error (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bandly-algolia-firebase/node_modules/algoliasearch/src/server/builds/node.js:227:14)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:308:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at connectErrorNT (net.js:1015:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

The actual code in question is here:

```
/**
 *  Adding or updating a record from Algolia
 */
function addOrUpdateIndexRecord(dataSnapshot) {
  // Get Firebase object
  var firebaseObject = dataSnapshot.val();
  // Specify Algolia's objectID using the Firebase object key
  firebaseObject.objectID = dataSnapshot.key;
  // Add or update object
  index.saveObject(firebaseObject, function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log('Firebase object indexed in Algolia', firebaseObject.objectID);
  });
}
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like the app ID is somehow being used as the hostname. Can you compare your code with what's in the repo here and see if anything sticks out? https://github.com/algolia/algolia-firebase-nodejs

Comment: yeah what's interesting is in that git repo you shared, when I run `node loadFirebase`, it says "Contacts loaded to firebase", but when I try to run `node importFirebaseToAlgolia` or `node syncFirebaseToAlgolia`, it gives me that same AlgoliaSearchNetworkError :/ And from what I can tell, my `.env` vars are all correct

Answer (score 1):

So as embarassing as it is, I actually made a mistake in the `.env` file and was putting quotes around the values. DO NOT put quotes around the values for each property.

Everything works as expected now.